# Menhir separated_nonempty_list generates code with type error

Tags: ocaml, ocamlyacc, menhir

I have a simple recursive rule:

```
i_stmt:
  | CHAIN LPAREN c=separated_nonempty_list(i_stmt, COMMA) RPAREN {Chain c}
  | ASSIGN LPAREN n=i_var COMMA e=i_expr RPAREN {Assign (n,e)}
  | CRETURN LPAREN i=i_expr RPAREN { Return i }
  ;
```

It is compiled OK by Menhir, but ocamlc complains about generated code:

```
File "parser.mly", line 38, characters 72-73:
Error: This expression has type unit list
       but an expression was expected of type Ast.istmt list
       Type unit is not compatible with type Ast.istmt
```

Type definition:

```
type istmt =
  | Chain of (istmt list)
  | Assign of ivar*iexpr
  | Return of iexpr
```

I've attempted to add:

```
%type <Ast.istmt> i_stmt
```

But it did not help either. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [menhir](http://pauillac.inria.fr/~fpottier/menhir/manual.pdf#figure.3) manual :

> `separated_nonempty_list(sep,X)` a nonempty sequence of `X`’s separated with `sep`’s

So you should write

```
| CHAIN LPAREN c=separated_nonempty_list(COMMA, i_stmt) RPAREN {Chain c}
```

Comment: These kind of things happen to anyone. Have fun. ;-)